# Detecting blobs that connects to any other blob, maybe with OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv

In the image, I connects to universe, but II and III not.

I need to detect both II and III, also I if possible.

Is it possible with current computer vision libraries?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Flood fill  the background, then hough transform to pick out rough circles II and III